# Не могу получить доступ к файлу

Tags: c#

Делаю программу, где в одном проекте клиент, а в другом сервер. Клиент отсылает запрос серверу в виде строки с координатами углом прямоугольника и цвета. Передаю с помощью MemoryMappedFile.
Вылезает исключение в Task8(1) в строке
`MemoryMappedFile SharedMemory=MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(path,FileMode.OpenOrCreate,"SharedMemory",4096,MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWriteExecute);`

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.
```

Task8(1).cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.IO;
    using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Text;
    using Task8;
    
    namespace Task8 {
    
     
        public class Client
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string path = "C:\\Users\\Максим\\source\\repos\\Os_Lab4\\Task8\\SharedMemory.txt";
                File.Create(path);
    
                Console.WriteLine("Client");
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter angles coordinates and color");
    
                char[] message = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
                //Размер введенного сообщения
                int size = message.Length;
               
                MemoryMappedFile SharedMemory=MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(path,FileMode.OpenOrCreate,"SharedMemory",4096,MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWriteExecute);
    
    
                //Создаем объект для записи в разделяемый участок памяти
                using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor writer = SharedMemory.CreateViewAccessor(0, size * 2 + 4))
                {
                    //запись в разделяемую память
                    //запись размера с нулевого байта в разделяемой памяти
                    writer.Write(0, size);
                    //запись сообщения с четвертого байта в разделяемой памяти
                    writer.WriteArray<char>(4, message, 0, message.Length);
                }
    
    
                Console.WriteLine("Сообщение записано в разделяемую память");
                Console.ReadLine();
    
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Task8.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Task8
{
    public class Task8
    {
        private Semaphore semaphore;
        static HttpListener server1 = new();
        static HttpListener server2 = new();
        public Task8()
        {
            server1 = new();
            server2 = new();
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Server started");
            server1.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:8080/");
            server1.Start();
             for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
              {
                  Process process = Process.Start("C:\\Users\\Максим\\source\\repos\\Os_Lab4\\Task8(1)\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0\\Task8(1).exe");
             }
            Draw(server1);
        }
        public static void Draw(HttpListener server)
        {
            string path = "C:\\Users\\Максим\\source\\repos\\Os_Lab4\\Task8\\SharedMemory.txt";
            HttpListenerContext context = server.GetContext();
            HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
            HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
            char[] message;
            //Размер введенного сообщения
            int size;
            
            MemoryMappedFile SharedMemory = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("SharedMemory",MemoryMappedFileRights.Read);
            using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor reader = SharedMemory.CreateViewAccessor(0, 4, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
            {
                size = reader.ReadInt32(0);
            }
            using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor reader = SharedMemory.CreateViewAccessor(4, size * 2, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
            {
                //Массив символов сообщения
                message = new char[size];
                reader.ReadArray<char>(0, message, 0, size);
            }
            while (true)
            {
              
                string[] line = (message.ToString()).Split();
                int x, y, x1, y1;
                int.TryParse(line[0], out x);
                int.TryParse(line[1], out y);
                int.TryParse(line[2], out x1);
                int.TryParse(line[3], out y1);
                string width = Math.Abs(x1 - x) + "";
                string height = Math.Abs(y1 - y) + "";
                string color = line[4];
                string rect = "<svg>\r\n    <rect x=\"" + line[0] + "\" y=\"" + line[1] + "\" width=\"" + width + "\" height=\"" + height + "\"/>\r\n</svg>";
                //     Data.figures.Add(rect);
              
                string html = "<HTML><BODY>" +rect+ "</BODY></HTML>";
                byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);
                response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
                System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
                output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                output.Close();
         
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ReadWriteExecute` - `Execute` вам не нужен, и возможно в нем проблема.

Comment: Действительно из-за этого. но теперь вылазит ошибка, что файл используется другим процессом. Клиент и сервер, видимо, одновременно его используют. Вообще у меня должно быть два сервера и 5 клиентов, но я пока просто тестировал и поэтому 1 клиент и сервер. Как бы это  все правильно ограничить семафором для 5 клиентов и 2 серверов? Чтобы такой ошибки не было

Comment: Не работал с MMF, не подскажу

Comment: я могу сделать просто текстовый файл без MMF.тут дело не в MMF,а в том что я доступ к файлу не ограничил у процессов

Comment: Я бы через Pipes лучше сделал. Стрим как-то прикольнее, чем память.

Comment: Через pipe лучше ,конечно. Но раз так требует задание, буду пробовать с общей памятью